# How to stitch images vertically in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, panorama

For fun I want to stich together the [starwars saga](http://swanh.net/). I have the images downloaded and I am stiching them in chunks.
The problem is when a graphic element is duplicated and also rotated in separate files Photoshop stacks them together in the panorama function. No matter what feature I use in the panorama. See [here](https://imgur.com/a/gAoYB).

I just want to load 10 images a time or however my RAM can handle and have the images stacked one against the other in sequence. Preferably in vertical as seen in the first link.

Comment: wow, that is one impressive series of images! Is there a reason why you want to stitch them all together? That would be one very tall image!